# Отправка формы 2 раза Yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, html-form

У меня есть форма. Для ее отправки я использую ajax. То есть, пишу код

```
$("#editEvenForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/my/schedule/edit',
        type: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            var data=JSON.parse(res);
            msg(data[0].sms, data[0].status);
            if (data[0].status=='success'){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Вот сама форма

```
<?php $form=ActiveForm::begin([
                            'id'=>'editEvenForm',
                            'action'=>'/my/schedule/edit'
                        ]); ?>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Редактировать событие</h4>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="Schedule[id]" id="ev-id">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                <div class="col-md-2"><?= $form->field($shedule, 'time')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                                        'mask' => '99:99',
                                        'options'=>[
                                            'class'=>'form-control',
                                            'id'=>'ev-time'
                                        ]
                                    ]); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <?= $form->field($shedule, 'gid')->dropDownList(\common\models\groups\Group::getOptionGroup(), [
                                        'prompt' => 'Выберите группу',
                                        'id' => 'gid_edit'
                                    ]); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php if (Yii::$app->user->identity->type==2){ ?>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="revert-event">Вернуть на доработку</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="accept-event">Утвердить</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
                        </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close-add-event2" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-event" data-dismiss="modal">Удалить</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

После отправки формы, она отправляется 2 раза, то есть console.log() выводится 2 раза. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Можете на jsFiddle залить код и подправить так, чтобы была данная проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите вкладку Network - что за запросы уходят к серверу, один или два? Чем они отличаются? Возможно, это связано с ajax-валидацией.

Comment: Вам надо добавить e.preventDefault(); return false; ПОСЛЕ всего вызова $.ajax (Источник - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121958/jquery-ajax-post-inside-a-form-prevent-form-submission-on-ajax-call)

Comment: Отрабатывает стандартный сабмит и плюс еще данные отправляются ajax. Вероятно что-то спроектировано не так, потому что какой смысл использовать ajax, если потом все рано релоадить страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит, потому что вы не отключили стандартный сценарий обработки формы.
Вы просто к существующей форме прикрутили еще и отправку данных через ajax, если вы хотите чтоб она 1 раз, то вы можете хардкодом запретить отправку через onsubmit, или не изобретать костыли с ajax и использовать встроенные методы pjax
кстати в форме включите ajax validate 
Я попытался воспроизвести проблему, и у меня так же отправляло 2.
[Ознакомтесь вот с этой статьей, я думаю вы после решите свою проблему](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-vnikaem-v-pjax.html)